# Laravel Sentry Subdomain Cookie

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I use Sentry on laravel 4.2 Users login with sentry in mydomain com but when go to  wildcard domain  (test.mydomain com) became logout.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your `app/config/session.php` configuration.

Comment: `return array(
 'driver' => 'file',
 'lifetime' => 120,
 'expire_on_close' => false,
 'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
 'connection' => null,
 'table' => 'sessions',
 'lottery' => array(2, 100),
 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
 'path' => '/',
 'domain' => null,
 'secure' => false,

);
`

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code, don't post it in comments.

Comment: Also try changing the `domain` value from `null` to `.mydomain.com`.

Comment: its run very thanks.